# How do I redirect to a new page from inside a class called by an ajax command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm working with an asp.net MVC project.  A coworker was new to MVC and handled all of the populating of data and click actions by using ajax calls.  I know this isn't how MVC should be set up, but it's what I'm stuck with.  I'm just trying to work around that the best I can.  Anyway, within the method the ajax goes to, I need to redirect the user to a new page.  How do I do that?

I tried Response.Redirect, but I got an error saying it didn't exist.  I tried to add a using class, but couldn't it to work.

I found System.Diagnostics.Process.Start, but it opens in a new browser tab.  Could there possibly be a way to open in the same tab?

So here's the ajax call.  This is triggered in a javascript function when the user clicks a button:

```
 $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            url: "/api/WoApi/PostWoApprGen/" + vUsr,
            data: JSON.stringify(invObj),
            success: function (res)
            {
                if (res)
                {
                    var inv = $('#DivInv');
                    inv.html(res);

                    output = $('#TmpMsg');
                    output.html("");

                    opStatMsg("success", "rptGenWin");

                }
                else
                {
                    opStatMsg("error", "rptGenWin");
                }
            }
        });
```

That goes to a class in the controller directory, filename WoApiController.cs:

```
public string PostWoInv([FromBody] Koorsen.OpenAccess.WrkOrdTemp obj)
    {
        var currentUser = ClsUtility.GetCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == 0)
        {
            rep.UpdateWorkOrderStatusInvoiced(obj.WoTempId, currentUser, obj);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("~Admin/Login");
        }
.............
.............
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. ajax calls do not redirect. If you want to redirect, make a normal submit.

Comment: I know, but a coworker set up these ajax calls.  I'm stuck with this.  Anyway that I can get this to work?

Comment: In the success callback - `location.href = 'someUrl';`

Comment: Anyway to get this to work server side?

Answer (score 0):

In your success callback, simply do

```
location.href = 'Home/Index';
```

or, preferably, using Razor and a method called `Index` in `HomeController`

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
```

Comment: Thanks.  Anyway to get this to work on the server side?  The success callback will not need to redirect unless there's a time out issue so it couldn't go there unless I had someway to pass to the success section that it sometimes should process normally and other times redirect.